# How to setup server side sent event with Django response

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm in the middle of implementing server sent event using Django.

**HTML**

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    var source = new EventSource('/pro_listen');
    console.log(source);
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event.data);
    };
 </script>
```

and pro_listen code is here.

**views**

```
def pro_listen(request):
    return HttpResponse("{'data':'new'}", content_type="text/event-stream")
```

So the real problem is why `console.log(event.data);` doesn't print anything...

**Update:**

After tried with `StreamingHttpReponse` `event.data` still doesn't print anything ...

Please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Server Side Events and other persistent connections are not natively supported by Django and you should use a dedicated async framework such as [Tornado](https://tornadoweb.org/en/stable) for this type of functionality.